# Center text in fixed height div, text without break

Tags: javascript, html, css

The div always has a fixed height. The text in it should always be centered. As soon as the text becomes larger than the div, the font-size should become smaller so that the text is centered in the div.
The problem is, I can not add different classes to the headings.
Has anyone an idea how I can solve this? Do I need javascript?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```css
.fix-height{
  height: 60px;
  width: 270px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

h2{
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-height">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="fix-height">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
<div class="fix-height">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple JQuery

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#fitin div').css('font-size', '1em');

  while ($('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height()) {
    $('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px");
  }

});
```

```css
#fitin {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

#fitin div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fitin">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** Aligned the text in center

Comment: OP says: `The text in it should always be centered`

Answer (score 1):

[FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) is a Javascript-Library i used in past projects. You can define a range of font-sizes and it takes the biggest one possible.

Answer (score 0):

add css

```
.fix-height{
display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this, thanks! but it's only centred in vertical, not in horizontal

Comment: add css   "text-align: center; "

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how can I solve the Problem, the text should never become larger than the div?